# Div background doesn't show

Tags: html, css, positioning

Why my div's background doesn't show normally? Here's the code:

```
<div style="
    width:676px; 
    height:230px; 
    display: inline; 
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
    background-image: url('http://www.goodsstall.co.uk/ekmps/shops/goodsstall/resources/Design/becomefan.png');">    
</div>
```

My idea is to make div with width of 676px and height 230px, which would have background image  http://www.goodsstall.co.uk/ekmps/shops/goodsstall/resources/Design/becomefan.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `display:inline` then you'll be able to see it. [Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WjHF4/).

If you need it to be inline, consider using `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

[Float reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float)
[Display reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display)

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, will accept after couple mins :)

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lufq8/)